# Left shift on an unsigned short without overflow into an integer

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, overflow, bit-shift

if I've a ushort variable which is 0xFFAA and I'll left shift this with 8 bits, I'll get an integer not an unsigned short, why?
Here a picture to make you more clear, what I mean:

[image]

Is there a way to get from this left shift a 16 bit variable without casting the int into an unsigned short?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with UINT not being part of the CLS?

`The UInt16 type is not CLS-compliant. The CLS-compliant alternative type is Int32. Int16 can be used instead to replace a UInt16 value that ranges from zero to MaxValue. For more information about CLS compliance, see Common Language Specification.`

Comment: `test` is not a ushort here; it is an `int`. `var` typing with integer constants always gives `int`.  Even without C#'s rules for type promoting in shifts, there's no reason to expect a `ushort` out.

Comment: The same occurs if I'm using ushort instead of var.

Comment: That's a different question than the one you asked, and the answer is simply from C#'s type promotion rules.  The output of `ushort << anything` is an `int`, by definition.  If you want a `ushort` out, you have to cast the `int` to a `ushort`.  You ask "without casting the int to an unsigned short", but why?  Kind of like asking how to milk a cow without squeezing the nipples.

Comment: The reason why I'm confusing is simple. I came from the low level programming. If i shift left into a register, the problem will not occour, the bytes (0xFF in my Example) will be "removed". So your example with the cow isnt' right here, because you can do something like I explained without casting in low level. But you answered my question, the reason is C#.

Comment: I see the misconception now.  Don't think of a bitshift operation as in place.  Even if it's implemented as an in place modification to a register value at the lowest level, that's not how C# shifts it.  `c = a << b` takes `a`, shifts it by `b`, and assigns the result to `c`.  Nothing is done in place and so `c` can easily have a different type than `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that only the lower 16 bits of a variable are set, you can mask with `0xFFFF` using logical AND:

```
var supposed = (test << 8) & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works as aspected. Can you maybe tell me, why my way doesn't work as supposed?

Comment: As mentioned by user5090812, test is an int, so shifting it up 8 bits gives 0x00FFAA00. Specifying a hex constant value with 4 digits doesn't make test a ushort.